# Unity2D C# - How to create an all-purpose prefab instantiator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a function in C# that can choose a prefab from my prefab folder, add it to the game, and allow me to set the properties of that prefab if I want. The function I have now:

```
public void loadObject(string objReference, float xPos, float yPos){
    Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(objReference),xPos,yPos);

    //I want access to the prefabs properties
}
```

I can also call the function and load the prefab from anywhere in my class:

```
loadObject ("Prefab/BeamPlatform", this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y);
```

When it was just the string I was passing to the function, it worked:

```
public void loadObject(string objReference){
    Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(objReference));
}

//

loadObject ("Prefab/BeamPlatform");
```

But as soon as I try to control the position of the prefab, I get a couple of errors:

[image]

Am I just passing arguments incorrectly? What am I doing wrong? Is this actually possible? I'm used to doing this in AS3 and it was as easy as:

```
public function loadObject(objClass, xPos:Number, yPos:Number){
   var obj = new objClass();
   obj.x = xPos;
   obj.y = yPos;
   obj.otherProperty = ;
}
```

I'm trying to avoid setting up a class level variable and dragging the prefab onto it in the inspector. I feel like that would limit my options, but I'm listening to any advice.

[Here's what it looks like when it works with just a string passed](https://youtu.be/3HQLThclQcQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because are not providing the correct parameter to the Instantiate function. Awlays good idea to read the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

This is what it looks like:

```
Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
```

This is the way you are trying to use it:

```
Instantiate(Object original, float position, float rotation);
```

That's because `xPos` and `yPos` are both `floats`. You need to convert both of them to `Vector3` then pass it to the `Instantiate` function.

This should work:

```
public void loadObject(string objReference, float xPos, float yPos)
{
    Vector3 tempVec = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0);
    Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(objReference), tempVec, Quaternion.identity);

    //I want access to the prefabs properties
}
```

Also, if you need to access the instantiated prefab property, you need to get the object the `Instantiate` function returned and store it to a temporary variable:

```
public void loadObject(string objReference, float xPos, float yPos)
{
    Vector3 tempVec = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0);
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(objReference), tempVec, Quaternion.identity);

    //I want access to the prefabs properties
    Debug.Log(obj.transform.position);

    string val = obj.GetComponent<YourScriptName>().yourPropertyName;
    obj.GetComponent<YourScriptName>().yourFunctionName();
}
```